# Term, preferably a single word, that describes a person's occupation?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology, business-language

For example, a *demonym* is *the name given to the inhabitants of a particular location*.

Demonym: *United States* -> *American*

Is there a word for *the name given to people that do a certain job*?

(Word I'm looking for): *Cooking* -> *Cook*

Comment: What's wrong with "occupation"?

Comment: I understand “occupation” as meaning the activity that someone does (i.e. “plumbing”), rather than what you call the person that does that job (“plumber”). But it gets murky with other examples, like “lawyer”, so maybe I’m wrong?

Comment: An argument in favour of my thesis that “occupation” = “activity” is that you can’t say “My occupation is lawyer.”, but rather “My occupation is _being_ a lawyer.”

Comment: One thing that seems clear is that the term you are seeking is not analogous to "demonym".  So often on this site people expect English to behave consistently. The history of our language, and its extensive idiomatic usage does not allow for that.

Comment: I disagree with your thesis. When filling in a form that asks for your occupation, it would be normal to put 'plumber', 'librarian' or whatever.

Comment: Some demonyms work as both adjective and noun e.g. "The American I met had an American accent". But it doesn't work with all demonyms. "French", "English" etc are not available as nouns.

Comment: Are you looking for a word that categorized people by their career fields, as demonym defines words which categorize people by the locations of their residences?

Comment: @Davo Yes, "demonym" was just an example of a similar word.

Comment: I don't believe that there is a specific term for words that identify jobs.

Comment: Scribu seems to be suggesting that *Demonym* would mean *name derived from place lived in* which *logically* would mean *United States = American*.
Why should’t *name derived from occupation* be equally reasonable?
Not speaking Latin, I recognise a score of words for *work*. Just perhaps most obviously that might be *laboraronym*. Another choice might be *oponym*. I think that’s closer; I also think it’s less obvious to Mr or Mrs Average.
Given the number of English names any and all of you can trace to someone’s occupation, how could that not matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Closest thing I can think of is **job title**, according to [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/job-title):

> a name that describes a person's job in an organization

And their example sentence:

> My official **job title** is Deputy Manager.

#### Background on your example

Cook is probably not a full job title, most kitchens have more than one cook and they have different titles (somewhat similar to military ranks, but even more specific to what they actually do, rather than just indicating a hierarchy). [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brigade_de_cuisine) has quite an extensive list, including but not limited to the following job titles (French in brackets, although the French title may be used in England as well):

> head chef (*chef de cuisine*)
>
> deputy chef (*sous-chef*; this probably more common than the English version)
>
> pastry cook (*pâtissier*)

Attribution:

[1](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/job-title) "Job Title Definition and Meaning | Collins English Dictionary." Complacent Definition and Meaning | Collins English Dictionary. Accessed May 05, 2018. https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/job-title.

[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brigade_de_cuisine) "Brigade De Cuisine." Wikipedia. April 30, 2018. Accessed May 05, 2018. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brigade_de_cuisine.

Comment: Except lots of people ***do*** a lot of stuff that does not come under the rubric of their "job title."

Comment: I think you’ve cracked it. It’s not a fancy single word, but it does the job. :)

Answer (score -3):

Given that no existing word suits this function, we can propose a new one.

If *demonym* is based on *demo* for people + *nym* for name, then *opunym* from *opus* for occupation would be consistent.

Giving us:

- demonym
- eponym
- opunym

Comment: The OED contains 50 words that end "-nym" - none of them refer to a job title. There have been about 1,500 years for English to develop a "-nym" word... but it did not. A nonce word that even native speakers do not understand is not going to solve the OP's problem.

Comment: @Greybeard Someone had to create those words, did they not? Limiting our vocabulary (stagnation) does not seem like a better option

Comment: Words get added every year to that dictionary: https://public.oed.com/updates/new-words-list-march-2021/